# comparison of %2B in perl

Tags: perl

I'm just trying to check if a string is equal to "%2B", and if it does I change it to "+".
The problem lies in comparison.

```
if ($lastItem == "%2B"){
   $lastItem = "+";
}
```

When $lastItem is something completely different (like "hello"), it will still go into the statement. I've been wracking my brain and I just can't tell where I've gone wrong. Does %2B have some special meaning? I'm very new to perl.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`eq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) when comparing strings, or perl will try to convert the string to a number (which will be `0`), and you will find such oddities as `"a" == 0` to evaluate true. And when comparing two strings, you will of course effectively get `if (0 == 0)`, which is the problem you are describing.

```
if ($lastItem eq "%2B") {
```

It is important to note that if you had used `use warnings`, this problem would have been easier to spot, as this one-liner will demonstrate:

```
$ perl -wE 'say "yes" if ("foo" == "bar")'
Argument "bar" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
Argument "foo" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
yes
```

Comment: @user1126345 If you feel this answered your question, you can click the check mark to the left to "accept" it.

Comment: Oh sure thing, yeah I'm still new here. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

I think you really want the following:

```
use URI::Escape qw( uri_unescape );

my $unescaped_last_item = uri_unescape($escaped_last_item);
```

[URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aEscape)

Please use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score 2):

Another example where turning on `use warnings` would have made it simpler to work out what was wrong.

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -e'$l = "x"; if ($l == "%2B") { print "match\n" }'
Argument "%2B" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
Argument "x" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
match
```